# My contact form don't work

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, web

please help me with following contact form.

I made a contact form following a tutorial. Uploaded it on wamp as well to test it. But I still keep getting an error, but I am really unable to find what's the error. Maybe because I am unaware of PHP. Can someone please check my code and let me know the problem. I believe the problem is a very small one. Thank you.

```
<?php
            $name = $_POST['InputName'];
            $email = $_POST['InputEmail'];
            $message = $_POST['InputMessage'];
            $from = 'From: Blueblink - contact'; 
            $to = 'kkalamarz@gmail.com'; 
            $subject = 'Hello';

            $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";
            ?>


            <?php
            if ($_POST['submit']) {
                if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
                    echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
                } else { 
                    echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
                }
            }
            ?> // Php form: contactform.php //

        <form role="form" action="contactengine.php" method="post" >
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="InputName">Twoje imie</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="InputName" id="InputName" placeholder="Name" required>
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></i></span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="InputEmail">Email</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="InputEmail" name="InputEmail" placeholder="Email" required  >
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></i></span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="InputMessage">Wiadomość</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <textarea name="InputMessage" id="InputMessage" class="form-control" rows="5" required></textarea>
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></i></span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Wyślij" class="btn wow tada btn-embossed btn-primary pull-right">
            </div>
        </form>  // Website code //
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read rules before asking a question.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: i get: "somethink went wrong"; Any mail dont come to me..

Comment: put error_reporting(E_ALL); at the top of your php code

Comment: nothing happened after adding error_reporting.